# Calculating Earnings per Share for Berkshire Hathaway

Tags: united-states, investing, accounting, earnings-per-share

I am looking at page 5 of the following earnings release: [Form 10-Q (Q2 2021)](https://www.berkshirehathaway.com/qtrly/2ndqtr21.pdf)

I want to calculate the earnings per B-Share. I do this with the following
calculations:

```
 28094e6  / ( 1519576*1500 + 2279363382 )
```

The numerator is the total earnings, the two numbers in the dividend represent the number of class A and class B shares outstanding. You will notice that one of the numbers is multiplied by 1500. This is because 1 class A share is the equivalent of 1500 B shares.

When I do the calculations, I get earnings per share of 6.1626848. However, the report shows earnings of 12.33. What am I missing?

Comment: Note `12.33` *just so happens* to be *exactly* (to three digits)) 2x that of `6.16`.    That should be a clue as to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is you double counted.

The table in the [Form 10-Q (Q2 2021)](https://www.berkshirehathaway.com/qtrly/2ndqtr21.pdf) you pulled the numbers from includes the following:

> Class B shares are economically equivalent to one-fifteen-hundredth of
> a Class A share. Accordingly, net earnings per average  equivalent
> Class B share outstanding is equal to one-fifteen-hundredth of the
> equivalent Class A amount. See Note 17.  See accompanying Notes to
> Consolidated Financial Statements

The key is note 17

> Since we have two classes of common stock, we provide earnings per
> share data on the Consolidated Statements of Earnings for  average
> equivalent  Class A  shares  outstanding  and  average  equivalent
> Class B  shares  outstanding.  Class B  shares  are  economically
> equivalent  to  one-fifteen-hundredth  (1/1,500)  of  a  Class A
> share.  Average  equivalent  Class A  shares  outstanding  represents
> average  Class A  shares  outstanding  plus  one-fifteen-hundredth
> (1/1,500)  of  the  average  Class B  shares  outstanding.  Average
> equivalent  Class B shares outstanding represents average Class B
> shares outstanding plus 1,500 times the average Class A shares
> outstanding.

That essentially means they already did the math you did. When you repeated the calculation you ended-up double counting the shares.